# Given a group $G$, is there any algorithm / method to check whether a group is sequenceable, or this problem is NP- hard?

Tags: algorithms

The title of the question says it all: just recall that
A non-trivial finite group $G$ of order $n$ is said to be **sequenceable** if its elements can be arranged in a sequence $(b_1, b_2,\ldots , b_n)$ in such a way that the partial products $(a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n)$, where $a_i = b_1b_2\cdots b_i$, are distinct. The sequence $(b_1, b_2, \ldots, b_n)$ is called a sequencing for $G$. If $(b_1, b_2, \ldots , b_n)$ is a sequencing for $G$ then $b_1 = e$, where $e$ is the identity of $G$.

Comment: Take a look at M. A. Ollis, "Sequenceable groups and related topics", The Electronic Journal of Combinatorics 20 (2) (2013). This is an updated version of a 2002 survey in the same journal. It's really not an active area, so this is pretty much up to date.